# Kernel system call to create a new file

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to learn some concepts about the VFS in the Linux Kernel and I can't seem to find which call(s) are made when creating a new file. I am specially interested in knowing how to know if the folder the file is going to be created in is a valid folder. Could some one point in the direction of the system call(s) to create a new file?

P.S. I'm using kernel 3.4

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about user space (which I assume because you asked about system calls), then one of the easiest ways to determine which calls are invoked is to use the `strace` utility.

Here, I'm using the `touch` utility to create a file.

```
$ rm foo; strace touch foo
```

Looking at the resulting output where `foo` is referenced we see:

```
open("foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

This should give you some clues to dig down further.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at kernel sources: linux/fs/open.c. There is definition of sys_open() function (SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open,)...). AFAIK this function is called when you call open() from userspace.